# Dependent maven projects heroku or google cloud deployment

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, heroku, jar

I have a maven project which **name is B** and also a maven project which **name is A**.
**Project A** provides many pojos and utils and It's **packaged as jar**, then **B uses A as a maven dependency**. Both of them are spring-boot projects.

When I need to deploy Project B to heroku/google, **maven goal can not find Project A**, so that deployment is always **unsuccessful**. On the other hand, I don't want to publish my Project A to any public repository (maven central or other 3rd party mirrors).

Currently I deployed my project on a VPS and it works for test, because local env of VPS has Project A which is installed and Project B can find Project A in m2 local repository. But at the end of the day I need to deploy project B to heroku/google.

*How can I overcome that scenario **in order to deploy Project B**?*

Comment: are these maven project modules in the same repo?

Comment: Yes, it is., exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run Maven from the root directory (i.e. the parent of the two modules). On Heroku, you may also want to target project B like this:

```
$ heroku config:set MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS="-pl projectB"
```